# Outputting 'SUB' character in CSV file when mapping from XML in XSLT map

Tags: c#, xml, csv, xslt, hex

Our customer wants a 'SUB' character at the end of the CSV file, for the receiver to correctly process the file.

I've received in Excel document, where the character is displayed correctly. I've included it here.

Converting this to HEX yields: 1a

In my XSLT code I tried outputting this character using a CSharp script:

```
public string OutputEndOfFileCharacterSUB()
{
     return '\u001A'.ToString();
}
```

But when I build and test this, I get an error:

> XSLT compile error. '', hexadecimal value 0x1A, is an invalid
>   character.

My question is how I can output this character correctly in XSLT? Is it impossible, or should I use a different character?

Comment: If your XSLT code were using XML 1.1 you could insert/output/include that character as `&#x1A;`, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94rmq6U where Saxon 9.8 HE .NET and the IKVM platform with an XML parser supporting XML version 1.1 is used. If you use the Microsoft XML APIs then you don't have XML 1.1 support. However, you might be able to get away with `&#x1A;` by using XmlReader/WriterSettings with the CheckCharacters set to false. Not sure whether that works together with XslCompiledTransform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use System.BitConverter to convert that hexadecimal output to string.

```
public string OutputEndOfFileCharacterSUB()
{
     byte[] hexString = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes('\u001A'.ToString());
     return System.BitConverter.ToString(hexString);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This prints out 1A in my output CSV file when I open it in Notepad++. Would this be read as a SUB character?

Comment: you can add 0x to 1A if you want to show it as hexadecimal, which read as SUB character.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options, either switch to a parser supporting XML version 1.1 where a numeric character reference like `&#x1A;` is allowed in XML and there you could insert/output such a character in your XSLT code or use the exploit Microsoft has inserted in its XML APIs to not support XML 1.1 but neverthless allow such character references with XmlReaderSettings/XmlWriterSettings where the property `CheckCharacters` is set to false.

The latter suggestion requires you loading the XSLT stylesheet where you use the character reference with the appropriate XmlReaderSettings as well as writing out the stylesheet result with the same XmlWriterSettings:

```
        XmlReaderSettings xrs = new XmlReaderSettings() { CheckCharacters = false };

        XslCompiledTransform xsltProc = new XslCompiledTransform();

        using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create("sheet.xslt", xrs))
        {
            xsltProc.Load(xr);
        }

        XmlWriterSettings xws = xsltProc.OutputSettings.Clone();
        xws.CheckCharacters = false;

        using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create("result.csv, xws))
        {
            xsltProc.Transform("input.xml", null, xw);
        }
```

In the XSLT, where you want to output the character, you would use the character reference `&#x1A;`.

The first suggestion is possible for instance by switching to Saxon 9 .NET as it comes with the IKVM and a cross-compiled Java based XML parser that handles XML version 1.0 and 1.1.